# javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, anchor

I just had a question about the regex object in javascript...

My regex is this:

```
          data-href="[^"\r\n]*"
```

when I use it in this site: 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

matching against the following string:

```
       <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.org" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count"
```

it tests positive and returns the url. My goal is to dynamically change the value of data-href parameter for the div using javascript to dynamically include the anchors of the webpage (the site Im working on uses an ajax based navigation dependent on # anchors in the url).... And i really want the facebook button to be mutable so that when a person clicks "like", they dont just "like" the homepage.

how would I do that?

I tried various tutorials but couldn't get the regex to match at all (it always returned false).

where should I start?

thx!!!

Comment: Well, if you have `data-href="[^"\r\n]*"` then the attribute breaks and you actually have `data-href="[^"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the attribute using jQuery or any other JS-Framework. Then you don't need any regex. This

```
$(".fb-like").attr("data-href", window.location.href);
```

should do it.

Comment: .href - or do a find on nearest anchor and add that too

Comment: Suprise, you can do this even without jQuery! (Did you see any jquery tag in the question?)

Comment: I really like the jquery idea... is there a similar solution using pure javascript? just for curiosity though... 

I didn't check if that attr is what needed to be changed in the first place for the fb button to work differently... (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

as it turns  out the facebook button doesn't actually use the data-href attribute to specify the link it is going to use for its integration. My complete and fundamental misunderstanding.

Looks like it figures that out independently using a referrer or figures out what domain its script is running from... anyway, sorry about the hassle.